# Angular response headers in IE 11 not working properly unless in developer mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

So, this problem is a very strange one.

I've got code like the following:

```
httppromise=$http.get(url);
return httppromise.then(function(response) {
  $rootScope.id=response.headers("GetMyId");
```

This works 100% properly in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

However, in IE 11, it gets the value once.  On repeated calls, the value returned is the FIRST value, not the one it is receiving, no matter how many times the above code is called.  Interesting enough, if I turn on developer mode, it works PROPERLY.

Is there *ANY* solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not upvote my answer, if [THIS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8565) works for you, as obviously the possible solution for this problem is not contrived by me and I do not like to take credit for someone else's effort.

The symptoms described in the question are similar to what I've observed in my project and the solution posted Martinspire works for me. As http isn't my native language, I still have to decipher what he is exactly doing and how effectivly disabling the cache for angular-ajax-requests is impacting performance.

At least with me, my webapp feels as sluggish as before ;-)